# Diagnosing Rails 3 Heroku Slowness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a Rails 3 app that I am running on Heroku. The app is usually really fast but sometimes I'll get cases where the app seems to hang for upwards of 2 minutes before finally returning the requested page.

I have the New Relic addon installed and there doesn't seem to be anything sticking out at me. It seems to be kind of sporadic and doesn't seem to be connected to a particular controller/action.

How would you suggest I go about pinpointing the cause of this problem?

http://github.com/kyledecot/skateparks-web

Comment: Do you think the app is idling?

Comment: If the application is idling then that would explain what you are seeing. Are you on the free tier of Heroku?

Comment: No. I currently have the free web dyno as well as one additional web dyno.

Answer (score 0):

Always check the logs. When it happens, immediately go check your logs. Pretty sure all SQL queries are logged and timed, and you might want to add logging and timing to some of your own service calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to the Pro level of New Relic, you can get detailed traces specifically of your slow transactions. Turn up your [Transaction Trace threshold](http://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-agent-configuration#Transaction_Tracer) to a large number (1s is pretty big), and wait for traces to show up. You'll see a detailed breakdown of the performance of an individual request, including SQL queries.

(Full disclosure: I work for New Relic.)